# Filter out rows/columns with zero values in MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following panda MultiIndex dataframe in python

```
             0         1         2         3 
bar one  0.000000 -0.929631  0.688818 -1.264180
    two  1.130977  0.063277  0.161366  0.598538
baz one  1.420532  0.052530 -0.701400  0.678847
    two -1.197097  0.314381  0.269551  1.115699
foo one -0.077463  0.437145 -0.202377  0.260864
    two -0.815926 -0.508988 -1.238619  0.899013
qux one -0.347863 -0.999990 -1.428958 -1.488556
    two  1.218567 -0.593987  0.099003  0.800736
```

My questions, how can I filter out:

1. Columns that contains zero values -- column 0, in the above example.
2. With regrade to rows filtering. How can I filter rows with zeros: (bar, one) alone and how can I filter both (bar, one) and (bar, two)?

   (Apologies for my not native English ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To filter out columns that contain zero values, you can use

```
df2 = df.loc[:, (df != 0).all(axis=0)]
```

To filter out rows that contain zero values, you can use

```
df2 = df.loc[(df != 0).all(axis=1), :]
```

To filter out rows, you can use

```
df2 = df.drop('bar') ## drops both 'bar one' and 'bar two'
df2 = df.drop(('baz', 'two')) ## drops only 'baz two'
```

For example,

```
import numpy as np
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']), np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
df.ix['bar','one'][2] = 0
df = df.loc[:, (df != 0).all(axis=0)]
df = df.drop('bar')
df = df.drop(('baz', 'two'))

#                 0         1         3
# baz one  0.686969  0.410614  0.841630
# foo one  1.522938  0.555734 -1.585507
#     two -0.975976  0.522571 -0.041386
# qux one -0.991787  0.154645  0.179536
#     two -0.725685  0.809784  0.394708
```

Another way if you have no NaN values in your dataframe is to transform your 0s into NaN and drop the columns or the rows that have NaN:

```
df[df != 0.].dropna(axis=1) # to remove the columns with 0
df[df != 0.].dropna(axis=0) # to remove the rows with 0
```

Finally, if you want to drop the whole 'bar' row if there is one zero value, you can do this:

```
indices = df.loc[(df == 0).any(axis=1), :].index.tolist() ## multi-index values that contain 0
for ind in indices:
    df = df.drop(ind[0])
```

Comment: @Juilen, many thanks for the prompt reply. With regrading the rows. How can I condition on the rows that contain zeros. (Forget to mention this in my question)

Comment: @Dov I edited my answer. However, I do not know right now how to filter both 'bar one' and 'bar two' if only one of the two rows has a zero.

Comment: @Juilen, Great, Thanks!